# Find CheckBox that matches user input on Android

Tags: android

I have a webview that saves user input into a field. I already have the method that takes in that input but I'm trying to figure out how to use that input to gray out the CheckBox with the same name as the string.

I think I use getIdentifier() but I'm not sure. Is this the correct way to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

You can check out this stackOverflow answer for an implementation of checkboxes, if you set a tag on each checkbox you can look up the tag and compare with the input you have. this would happen in the `getView` of your adapter.
[StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9990676/how-can-i-get-values-from-checkbox-in-android)